# Oracle : specify a larger or smaller in date data type

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have a table with:

- two columns : `date_1` and `date_2`
- data type is `date` (dd-mm-yyyy)
- database is `oracle`

I want to know whether `date_1` is `greater` or `smaller` then `date_2`.

My script:

```
Decode (to_char(date_1,'yyyyddmm') > to_char(date_2,'yyyyddmm'), 'Greater','Smaller') as Status
```

CMIIW

Comment: Datatypes actually are decimal numbers, and you can treat them that way : sysdate + 0.5, or : sysdate < mydate, ... etc etc. Conversion to Character is mostly needed for "human readability" only. In addition, Oracle automatically displays any date with a given default format, when you just display a date column. The disadvantage is that it looks like it is storing it that way, but it really isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As datatype of both is date not need to convert those date into char.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN DATE_1 > DATE_2 THEN 'DATE_1 IS GREATER' 
            WHEN DATE_1 = DATE_2 THEN 'DATE_1 EQUAL to DATE_2'
                                 ELSE 'DATE_1 IS SMALLER'
       END
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert the dates to strings, just compare the dates directly:

```
SELECT date_1, date_2
      ,CASE WHEN date_1 > date_2 THEN 'Greater' ELSE 'Less than or Equal to' END AS Status
  FROM my_table
```

Comment: Operator `>`,`<`,`>=`,`<=` , cannot use with `decode`?

Comment: I guess you could do something hokey like `DECODE(GREATEST(date_1, date_2), date_1, 'Greater than or equal', 'Less than')`. Not sure if you can use boolean expressions in decode.